# Nested UpdatePanel Triggers

Tags: .net, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

My child UpdatePanel updates both its contents and those of its parent UpdatePanel.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" 
                 runat="server">
    ...
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" 
                     runat="server">
        ...
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    ...
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I don't want my parent UpdatePanel to be updated every time its child updates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the [UpdatePanel.UpdateMode Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.updatepanel.updatemode?view=netframework-4.8.1) to `Conditional`.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" 
                 UpdateMode="Conditional"
                 runat="server">
    ...
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

[Project Cool](https://web.archive.org/web/20200811165908/http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2007/05/16/112525.aspx):

> Child Update Panel refreshes only its
> contents and doesnt refresh that of
> the Parent Update Panel unless, the
> update mode for the parent update
> panel is not set to Conditional

[CodeClimber](https://web.archive.org/web/20220811230326/https://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2007/05/24/UpdateMode-default-value-for-the-UpdatePanel-is-Always.aspx):

> When set to Conditional, the
> UpdatePanel will be updated only on
> postback originated by controls inside
> the panel or from the triggers
> specified. So, if you have multiple
> update panels and you don't want to
> update all of them to be updated every
> time, you have to set the UpdateMode
> to Conditional.

Answer (score 6):

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" ChildrenAsTriggers="False"
                 UpdateMode="Conditional"
                 runat="server">

</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: This is the real answer

Answer (score 2):

This is what I do

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" ChildrenAsTriggers="False"
                 UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
    ...
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" ChildrenAsTriggers="False"
                 UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
        ...
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    ...
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In the code behind after binding UpdatePanel2 Controls with data, call UpdatePanel2.Update();
Ajax updates only HTML markup in "UpdatePanel2".

Comment: You don't need to handle it via code-behind. Just one ChildrenAsTriggers = false on the first UpdatePanel is enough. Besides, what if you have three or more nested panels?!